# How to get/find domain sid from machine sid

Tags: c#, wmi, directoryservices, sid

I can get machine Sid like below:

```
var dir = new DirectoryEntry($"WinNT://{Environment.MachineName},Computer");
var objSid = dir.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().First().InvokeGet("objectSID");
var secId = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])objSid, 0);
var machineSid = secId.AccountDomainSid.ToString();
```

I tried to find computer Sid from machine Sid but it is always NULL.

```
using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "AbcDomain", "userName", "password"))
{
    var pc01 = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.Sid, machineSid);
    //output: pc01 = null
    var pc02 = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.Name, "PC-JACKML5291");
    //output: pc02...

}
```

I want to check duplicate machine sid before calling `JoinDomainOrWorkgroup`.
Can I get the Computer SID (joined domain) from machine SID ?

Comment: secID is machine SID. Object SID is combined from AccountDomainSid and RID, RID is RelativeID. AccountDomainSid can be used to check two SIDs are from same domain.

Answer (score 0):

The machine SID is not the same as the SID of the computer object on the domain. They are different.

According to [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/the-machine-sid-duplication-myth-and-why-sysprep-matters/ba-p/723859),

> in order to assure uniqueness, the SID that Setup generates has one fixed subauthority value (21) and **three randomly-generated subauthority values** (the numbers following “S-1-5-21” in the output).

If you want the SID of the computer object on the domain, you will have to search for the object by the computer name.